# Trigger jQuery UI autocomplete at minLength = 3 but 1 when only digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete input field, and I want it to search on objects with a label (text) and an id (integer).

The autocomplete must allow users to search either on the textual label or the id. The server part is ok, but on the client part, I would like to trigger the search at minLength=3 when the user enters at least one letter, but at the first character when there is only digits (if not, it misses all ids <=99).

Code:

```
$("#my_input").autocomplete({
    minLength : 1,
    delay:200,  source: function(request,response){ 
       ... 
} });
```

How to prevent the autocomplete to trigger when less then 3 characters if there is at least 1 letter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `search` property to add additional checks before performing a search.

```
 search: function( event, ui ) {
    var value = document.getElementById('my_input').value;

    // If not a number and less than three chars, cancel search.
    if(isNaN(value) && value.length < 3){   
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

[See a full working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/eqk3cabf/)